Getting old results in JMeter results tree
I am using jmeter on Ubuntu to run some smoke tests against an API.
The tests are run on CLI with these parameters:
jmeter -t service.jmx -p test.properties -j /tmp/jmeter-service.log -l /tmp/jmeter-service.jtl -n

But sometimes (strangely not everytime) the results are not changing. Old results are displayed in the Results Tree. I can clearly see that other tests are run but I can't see them in the results.
This even happens even when I:

Right-click the tree and select "Clear"
Close JMeter and reopen it
The .jtl file in the /tmp folder has been removed and recreated by the tests

Can anyone help me out? Is there some sort of caching?


If you have results opened in JMeter GUI in View Results Tree listener and loading new results the new results will be appended to what you have in GUI
If /tmp/jmeter-service.jtl file exists and you run your test using the command you provided the new results will be added to the .jtl results file

So make sure to:

Clear the old results from GUI
Add -f command-line argument to your command, this way JMeter will overwrite the existing results (if any) and you will get "fresh" results in the .jtl results file

Combination of the above 2 points will give you the confidence that you're analyzing the "fresh" results.
More information:

Full list of command-line options
JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips


Thanks for the response. As I wrote, I have cleared the results, but was not aware of the -f option, nice! Found out the reason and will answer my question.

Found out the answer in another stack overflow question: Cannot see all results in Jmeter results tree and report
It seems I only saw the first 500 results, changed the user.properties file as recommended and now all is working fine.
Just to sum this up:
Change the user.properties file (located in the jmeter /bin directory) and add
view.results.tree.max_results=0

